# On Windows, what could be creating these strangely named, locked versions of .doc files?

Tags: windows, filesystems

I have a user who has .doc files called Foo.doc and Bar.doc. Later they find files named ~$01-1-Foo.doc and ~$05-1-Bar.doc in the same directory. The new files are locked and disrupting the operation of some other tools that can't read locked files.

What could be causing locked files with these strange names to be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they look indeed like MS Word temp files, to find out what's locking them, you may use this:

**[LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/)** is a foolproof file unlocker.

> It is a tool to delete files
>   blocked by something you do not know.
>   LockHunter is useful for fighting
>   against malware, and other programs
>   that are blocking files without a
>   reason. **Unlike other similar tools
>   it deletes files into the recycle bin
>   so you may restore them if deleted by
>   mistake**.

Key Features

> Shows processes locking a file or
>   folder
>
> Allows to unlock, delete, copy or
>   rename a locked file
>
> Allows to kill locking process
>
> Allows to remove locking processes
>   from hard drive
>
> Integrates in to Explorer menu
>
> It deletes files into the recycle bin,
>   so you may restore them if deleted by
>   mistake
>
> Supports both 32 and 64bit Windows

[image]

*LockHunter is freeware.*

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Word creates a mess of temporary files in a document's directory when one is open. It could be possible that a crash would keep them locked. Try using [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to unlock the files and then delete them.

Answer (score 1):

Is word running? They look like temp files.