# Mysterious copying of Invalid Word 2010 files upon each opening

Tags: microsoft-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On Windows, what could be creating these strangely named, locked versions of .doc files?](https://superuser.com/questions/66419/on-windows-what-could-be-creating-these-strangely-named-locked-versions-of-do)

Every time I open a Microsoft Word 2010 document, it makes a second copy in which the first two letters of the file name are replaced with  ~$. The Word logo next to the name is also fainter than the other documents. It's very strange, and when I try to open this version, which is always much smaller in size than the real version, a window that says it cannot be opened because of problems with the contents. I can easily delete the files, but it's tedious and pointless. Anyone know how to stop all this?

Answer (score 1):

In linux, Whenever someone opens a document with vim which is like command line's word, a ~backup.filename.swp is created, if you lose power or other things occur in which vim exits abnormally, the swp file keeps the changes that would have been lost.

In windows, I believe that this is the same type of instance occuring, although upon closure of the document, it should remove this file as vim does upon a clean exit.

tl;dr Its in case you lose your progress, I wouldnt recommend deleting them.

Comment: +1.  Additionally, they _should_ vanish when that document is properly closed.  If they are hanging around after Word is closed, and you aren't trying to recover anything, you can just delete them.  If they ALWAYS hang around, even when Word is closed properly, you've got other problems. ;)